# Почему в хроме в полноэкранном режиме не ставится фокус в адресной строке?

Tags: google-chrome

Почему в хроме в полноэкранном режиме не ставится фокус в адресной строке?

Как только перехожу в полноэкранный режим - <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> уже не срабатывает. Есть решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Что за хром такой? у меня полноэкранный режим на F11, а вот как раз F6 выделение адреса страницы. Но. в полноэкранном режиме не выделяется все равно ибо адресной строки там нет. Думаю Вам стоит писать в разрабам хрома, а то бишь в гугл.

Comment: @Tsyklop Все верно, вызов полноэкранного режима через f11, а вот фокус в полноэкранном режиме на адресной строке через f6 или ctrl + L - уже не срабатывает